# Clear the contents of the active sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm trying to clear the contents of certain cells in the active sheet of my google sheets spreadsheet. Here's what I have so far:

```
function Reset() {
  var sheet = sheetName();
  var range = sheet.getRange("B4:G53");
  range.clearContent();
}

function sheetName(){ 
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName();
}
```

I get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot find function getRange in object Copy of 5.7.18. (line 4, file "Code")

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your variable sheet doesn't make reference to a Class Sheet object.

Change

```
return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName();
```

by

```
return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
```